# writing to and reading from binary file java

Tags: java

I am compressing a text file using Huffman code I generated then I converted all characters to string of 0's and 1's. Wrote them in file using following code. (Input was `1011001110010011`)

```
public static void writeToFile(String binaryString, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException{
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < binaryString.length()){
        byte nextByte = 0x00;
        for(int i=0;i<8 && pos+i < binaryString.length(); i++){
            nextByte = (byte) (nextByte << 1);
            nextByte += binaryString.charAt(pos+i)=='0'?0x0:0x1;
        }
        writer.write(nextByte);
        pos+=8;
    }
}
```

Then I tried to regenerate previous binary string `1011001110010011` from the file I just created, using following code

```
data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    byte nextByte = data[i];
    String tempString = "";
    for(int j=0;j<8; j++){
        byte temp = (byte) (0x1 & nextByte);
        if(temp==0x1){
            tempString="1".concat(tempString);
        }else if(temp==0x0){
            tempString="0".concat(tempString);
        }
        nextByte = (byte) (nextByte >> 1);
    }
    binary=binary.concat(tempString);  
}
```

But I got `111011111011111010110011111011111011111010010011` in output, I was just expecting some attached 0's.

Edit: made change in from string to binary code, now its adding 0's at end to complete byte.

```
public static void writeToFile(String binaryString, BufferedWriter writer) throws IOException{
    int pos = 0;
    while(pos < binaryString.length()){
        byte nextByte = 0x00;
        for(int i=0;i<8; i++){
            nextByte = (byte) (nextByte << 1);
            if(pos+i < binaryString.length())
                nextByte += binaryString.charAt(pos+i)=='0'?0x0:0x1;
        }
        writer.write(nextByte);
        pos+=8;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: if you break the string into 8 bits at a time then `new BigInteger(eightBitString, 2).intValue()` gives you the same byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `BufferedWriter.write()` writes a `char`, not a `byte`. Whenever you're writing to the file, you're writing a variable-sized unicode character, not a single `byte`, so you're ending up with much more stored in your file than you were expecting.

You want to use

```
new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("filename"))
```

instead, and change the signature of your method to take an `OutputStream`.

(You might notice that `OutputStream.write()` takes an `int` rather than a `byte`, but that is just there to confuse you... it actually writes only the low-order byte, rather than the whole `int`, so it does what you want.)